# How to structure back to back to back Promise.all requests in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to perform a series of actions on a SPA website, but I'm running into an issue when dealing with Promise.all(). I was looking at the [Puppeteer docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) and following that example, but using `waitForSelector` rather than `waitForNavigation` since the page isn't actually changing. This might be important to note that the dropdown menu is fullscreen.

Basically what I want to achieve in words on a mobile device....

1. Go to a website
2. Click on the Hamburger menu icon (so the dropdown menu is revealed, which is fullscreen)
3. Click on a Menu item in the dropdown (this moves to the next sub-menu)
4. Click on a sub-menu item (this moves to the next sub-sub menu)
5. Click on a sub-sub-menu item (this is the last available menu)
6. And then get navigated to the sub-sub-menu item page

Below is the relevant code excerpt to perform the steps mentioned above, but on step 5... I get a "Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement" error, when I know that the node does exist and is visible. Any help on this?

```js
const performSteps = async () => {
  ...
  await page.goto('https://www.website.com'); // step 1
  await page.click('.hamburger-icon'); // step 2

  // Step 3
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector('menu-item'),
    page.click('menu-item'),
  ]);

  // Step 4
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector('sub-menu-item'),
    page.click('sub-menu-item'),
  ]);

  // Step 5 - results in ERR: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector('sub-sub-menu-item'),
    page.click('sub-sub-menu-item'),
  ]);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clicking it before it's there and visible. Try:

```
await page.waitForSelector('sub-sub-menu-item', {visible: true})
await page.click('sub-sub-menu-item')
```

In case it's not clear, the promises in Promise.all run at the same time, in this case you have to wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: I implemented what you had suggested and I believe it would have worked, but for some reason puppeteer can't "see" the selector. I get back a new error `TimeoutError: waiting for selector 'sub-sub-menu-item' failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded.`

In watching Puppeteer perform the actions, the right sub-sub menu screen shows up, but it just "hangs" there for a few seconds & goes back to the initial dropdown menu (start of step 3) until it times out... 

FYI: I got rid of all the `Promise.all()` in the code and replaced them with your suggestion.

Comment: I guess it's not there. You should set a breakpoint and try to find it in the browser elements panel

Comment: Update: I just tried using two different `sub-sub-menu-item` 's and they both worked without any problems! Since which `sub-sub-menu-item` gets selected is not important for me, I will just not use that problematic one. Thanks again @pguardiario

Comment: Also....I had tried using the Promise.all() approach (out of curiosity) with the different `sub-sub-menu-item` and that approach also worked. So it seems there was some visibility issue that was causing the problem.